# Modify a key-value in a json using jq with external command

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

Given a `json` file, how can I use `jq` and an external command to modify a value?

In my case, I want to convert a full timestamp to the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (for example, with the command: `date --date="2019-01-02T10:00:00.000Z" "+%Y-%m-%d"`)

Original JSON

```
[{"timestamp": "2019-01-01T10:00:00.000Z"}, {"timestamp": "2019-01-02T10:00:00.000Z"}, {"timestamp": "2019-01-02T10:00:00.000Z"}]
```

New JSON

```
[{"timestamp": "2019-01-01"}, {"timestamp": "2019-01-02"}, {"timestamp": "2019-01-02"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your sample input this should do it:

```
map(.timestamp |= .[:10])
```

If this looks oversimplifying, take a look at [jq's date manipulation builtins](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Dates); you **probably** don't need an external tool here.

Answer (score 3):

> how can I use jq and an external command to modify a value

It can be done, though it's not pretty:

```
jq --argjson update "$(jq -r '.[] | .timestamp' input.json |
    while read r ; do
      date --date="$r" "+%Y-%m-%d" 
    done |
    jq -nR [inputs] )" '
      reduce range(0;$update|length) as $i (.;
        .[$i].timestamp = $update[$i])
    ' input.json
```

(In some environments, it might be necessary to invoke `gdate` instead of `date`.)

Answer (score 1):

For time.json =

```
[{"timestamp": "2019-01-01T10:00:00.000Z"}, {"timestamp": "2019-01-02T10:00:00.000Z"}, {"timestamp": "2019-01-02T10:00:00.000Z"}]
```

Using

```
jq  '[.[]  | .timestamp |= (sub("\\.[0-9]+Z$"; "Z")  | fromdate | strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))]' time.json
```

produces

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-01-01"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-01-02"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-01-02"
  }
]
```

Edit Note:  The sub is because jq does *not* support milliseconds by default.  So in order to use the built in datetime functions you have to drop the milliseconds.  The other answers are functionally correct too.  But I like mine :-)